# Convert Document element to Protractor element

Tags: protractor

Is it possible to convert my jquery element to protractor element? For example:

```
browser.executeScript(() => {
    var ele = $(".datatable-row-wrapper .hdt-d:not('not-active')").get(0);
    return ele;
}).then(ele => {
    **//// this throwing error**
    element(ele).click();
});
```

Comment: you can directly use `ele.click()`

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to *instantiate an `ElementFinder` instance* (not tested):

```
var elementLib = require('protractor/built/element');
var ElementFinder = elementLib.ElementFinder;

var elementFinder = ElementFinder.fromWebElement_(browser, ele, by.css(".datatable-row-wrapper .hdt-d:not('not-active')"));
elementFinder.click();
```

Even though I've never encountered the need to actually do so.

The other way around - *passing an ElementFinder into a script* is much easier:

```
var elm = $(".datatable-row-wrapper .hdt-d:not('not-active')");
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elm.getWebElement());
```